# how to change the tab colour in ViewPager from black to white

Tags: android, android-actionbar, android-viewpager

I want to change the tab colour in the ViewPager. I search but didn't find any good solution for it. I want to change the tab colour from default that is from black to white. Is their any way to do this programatically for i have to modify style.xml. I don't know how to do as i am new to android.  plz somebody help

```
public class HomeActivity extends FragmentActivity implements ActionBar.TabListener 
    {

        public ViewPager viewPager;
        private PageAdapter mAdapter;
        private ActionBar actionBar;

        // Tab titles
        private String[] tabs = { "Calculate EMI", "EMI Schedule"};


        String TabFragmentSchedule;

         public void setTabFragmentSchedule(String t){
          TabFragmentSchedule = t;
         }

         public String getTabFragmentSchedule(){
          return TabFragmentSchedule;
         }


        @SuppressLint("NewApi")
        @Override
        protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) 
        {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setContentView(R.layout.activity_home);


            // Initilization
            viewPager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.pager);
            actionBar = getActionBar();
            ColorDrawable colorDrawable = new ColorDrawable(Color.parseColor("#0F7BFF"));
            actionBar.setBackgroundDrawable(colorDrawable);

            mAdapter = new PageAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager());


            viewPager.setAdapter(mAdapter);
            actionBar.setHomeButtonEnabled(false);
            actionBar.setNavigationMode(ActionBar.NAVIGATION_MODE_TABS);

            // Adding Tabs
            for (String tab_name : tabs) 
            {
                actionBar.addTab(actionBar.newTab().setText(tab_name).setTabListener(this));
            }

            /**
             * on swiping the viewpager make respective tab selected
             * */
            viewPager.setOnPageChangeListener(new ViewPager.OnPageChangeListener() {

                @Override
                public void onPageSelected(int position) {
                    // on changing the page
                    // make respected tab selected
                    actionBar.setSelectedNavigationItem(position);

                }

                @Override
                public void onPageScrolled(int arg0, float arg1, int arg2) {
                }

                @Override
                public void onPageScrollStateChanged(int arg0) {
                }
            });



        }

        //method that is called to swipe viewpage on button click from calculation fragment
         public void switchToFragmentSchedule(){
            // viewPager.setCurrentItem(1);
             viewPager.setCurrentItem(1, false);
          }

        @Override
        public void onTabReselected(Tab tab, FragmentTransaction ft) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        }

        @Override
        public void onTabSelected(Tab tab, FragmentTransaction ft) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

            viewPager.setCurrentItem(tab.getPosition());

        }

        @Override
        public void onTabUnselected(Tab tab, FragmentTransaction ft) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub


        }

    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You should style your theme in your xml files. You can find all the information for this task [here](https://developer.android.com/training/basics/actionbar/styling.html#CustomBackground).

If you need to change it programmatically, you can use

`mActionBar.setBackgroundDrawable(new ColorDrawable(0xffffffff));
mActionBar.setDisplayShowTitleEnabled(false);
mActionBar.setDisplayShowTitleEnabled(true);`

As a beginner, you might also find [this styling tool](http://jgilfelt.github.io/android-actionbarstylegenerator/#name=example&compat=holo&theme=light&actionbarstyle=solid&texture=0&hairline=0&neutralPressed=1&backColor=E4E4E4,100&secondaryColor=D6D6D6,100&tabColor=33B5E5,100&tertiaryColor=F2F2F2,100&accentColor=33B5E5,100&cabBackColor=FFFFFF,100&cabHighlightColor=33B5E5,100) very helpful.